# Packaging for reactor multi module build?

Tags: maven, build, module

I suppose I've made something wrong failing to find answer for basic philosophical question:

What is the correct packaging for reactor build module for multi module maven project?

I'm using `pom` but I don't feel it's correct since the pom artifact is used by no one:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-build</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>../config</module>
        <module>../module1</module>
        <module>../module2</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Comment: The pom packaging is correct. But based what you are using in your modules list like `../module1` etc. shows that the structure you are using is presumably wrong...cause your parent is not at the root of your directory structure....

Comment: Well it's a pom-only project, so `pom` packaging looks fine. There are anyway no other built-in packaging type that would suit better.

Comment: @khmarbaise, "reactor" project doesn't have to be a parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packaging `pom` is the only allowed packaging for aggregator projects, that is to say [a project with modules](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) like the one you have, and also for parent projects. From [Inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance):

> The `packaging` type required to be `pom` for *parent* and *aggregation* (multi-module) projects.

Any attempt to use a different packaging [will result in an error when trying to build the project](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/validation/DefaultModelValidator.java#L303-L308), such as the following when using `jar` (or keeping the default):

```
[ERROR] 'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging.
```

Comment: So I must simply live with such 'virtual' artifact in my repo?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Yes. The pom packaging also means "produces no main artifact". They are here to aid build other projects or let them inherit build element in the case of a parent.

Comment: But POM is available in repository as artifact, and it can be used as parent pom, for example.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo A project in the Maven sense is really just the POM file. While we generally deal with JAR or WAR projects that produce main JAR  WAR artifacts along with the Maven POM file, an aggregator project is just the POM file. It has to also be stored in the repository artifact for other project to be able to resolve it.